# Error bar sizes in a plotly scatter plot

Tags: r, plotly, errorbar, r-plotly, r-forestplot

This question follows [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870903/color-coding-error-bars-in-a-plotly-scatter-plot).

I'm plotting a [forst plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot) with `R` `plotly`, where I'm color coding the points and errors by their corresponding p-values.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)

factors <- paste0(1:25,":age")
effect.sizes <- rnorm(25,0,1)
effect.errors <- abs(rnorm(25,0,1))
p.values <- runif(25,0,1)
```

I'm adding `hoverover` text:

```
text.vec <- paste0(paste0("Factor: ",factors),"\n","Effect Size: ",effect.sizes,"\n","Effect Error: ",effect.errors,"\n","P-Value: ",p.values)
```

And then plotting it all:

```
yform <- list(categoryorder = "array",
              categoryarray = rev(factors),
              title="Factor",zeroline=F,showticklabels=T)

library(grDevices)
mycramp <- colorRamp(c("darkred","gray"))
mycolors <- rgb(mycramp(p.values),maxColorValue = 255)

library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  colorbar(limits=c(0,1),len=0.4,title="P-Value",inherit=FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(type='scatter',mode="markers",y=~factors,x=~effect.sizes,text=~text.vec,hoverinfo="text",
            color=~p.values,colors=grDevices::colorRamp(c("darkred","gray")),
            error_x=list(array=effect.errors,color=mycolors),split=factors,showlegend=FALSE,marker=list(color=mycolors)) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect Size",zeroline=T,showticklabels=T),yaxis=yform)
```

Gives:

[image]

So the color coding works great. However, it seems that the length of the error bars in the plot doesn't correspond to `effect.errors`. For example:

```
> factors[7]
[1] "7:age"
> effect.sizes[7]
[1] -0.8721795
> effect.errors[7]
[1] 0.1324996
```

and:

```
> factors[11]
[1] "11:age"
> effect.sizes[11]
[1] -1.198534
> effect.errors[11]
[1] 0.8714454
```

But in the plot you see that the error bars of `7:age` are much longer than that of `11:age`.

Am I missing some parameter when calling `error_x` `function`?

Comment: I think by removing `split=factors` it fixes your problem.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot @MLavoie

Comment: Actually, @MLavoie removing `split=factors` does solve the problem of the length of the error bars but messes up their color coding.